# How to configure celery for concurrent execution with multi-process?

Tags: python, django, concurrency, multiprocessing, celery

I have a task that talks to an external API, the `json` response is quite large and I have to make this call multiple times followed by further python processing. To make this less time-consuming, I initially tried:

```
def make_call(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

```
def make_another(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

```
def get_calls():
    return make_call, make_another
```

```
def task(*args, **kwargs):
    procs = [Process(target=get_calls()[i], args=(,), 
    kwargs={}) for i in range(3)]
    _start = [proc.start() for proc in procs]
    _join = [proc.join() for proc in procs]
```

```
# 
transaction.on_commit(lambda: task.delay())
```

However, I ran into an `AssertionError:` daemonic processes are not allowed to have children. What would be my best approach to speed up a celery task with additional processes?

Comment: Why have the separate/child calls anyway? It's an asynchronous task so it shouldn't matter if it takes a while

Comment: @lain that's kind of dismissive of the question and not a very good argument or helpful to the asker. If a task can be parallelized, say on multiple CPU cores or multiple I/O streams, why would you let it take longer than necessary? It could make a big difference in user responsiveness in an application. Say, a user waiting 10 seconds to process a long task vs 30 seconds or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Celery worker already creates many processes. Take advantage of the many worker processes instead of creating child processes. You can delegate work amongst the celery workers instead. This will result in a more stable/reliable execution.

You could either just create many tasks from your client code or make use of celery's primitives like [chains](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) or [chords](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) to parallelize the work. These can also be composed with other primitives like [groups](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#group-results), etc.

For example, in your scenario, you may have two tasks: one to make the API call(s) `make_api_call` and another to parse the response `parse_response`. You can *chain* these together.

```py
# chain another task when a task completes successfully
res = make_api_call.apply_async((0,), link=parse_response.s())

# chain syntax 1
result_1 = chain(make_api_call.s(1), parse_response.s())
# syntax 2 with | operator
result_b = make_api_call.s(2) | parse_response.s()

# can group chains
job = group([
   chain(make_api_call.s(i), parse_response.s()) 
   for i in range(3)
   ]
)
result = job.apply_async()
```

This is just a generic example. You can create task(s) and compose them to however your workflow needs. See: [Canvas: Designing Work-flows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) for more information.